# Get date difference using adx studio liquid template

Tags: html, adxstudio-portals

Im trying to get the day difference between two dates using adx studio liquid templates, my current code is

{%assign expirydate = bh_expirydate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' %}
{%assign datenow = now | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy' %}

{%assign diffdays = expirydate | minus: datenow %}
 I know that this line of code will not work, but the logic is that. I just can seem to find appropriate example. Can someone shed some light on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would do this without javascript, but here is my solution assuming *bh_expirydate* exists:

```
Days till expiry: <span id="expiryDays"></span>

<script>
Date.daysBetween = function( date1, date2 ) {
  //Get 1 day in milliseconds
  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  // Convert both dates to milliseconds
  var date1_ms = date1.getTime();
  var date2_ms = date2.getTime();

  // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
  var difference_ms = date2_ms - date1_ms;

  // Convert back to days and return
  return Math.round(difference_ms/one_day); 
}

  var dt1 = new Date();
  var dt2 = new Date('{{ bh_expirydate| date: "yyyy/MM/dd" }}');

  $('#expiryDays').text(Date.daysBetween(dt1, dt2));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Calculate years since first date until now

With the first assign we are taking the current time and subtracting a date of birth.
This will result in a timespan.  Convert it to a string and split to get the number of days in the first array element.
The second assign will take that first string element with the number of days and convert it into an integer.
The display will divide by 365 to give the years since dob.

```
{% if item.dob %}
{% assign words = now | minus: item.dob | string | split: '.' %}   
{% assign days = words.first | integer %}     
{{ days | divided_by: 365 }}
{% endif %}
```